# Pods frameworks in red (unrecognized by Xcode)

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode9

So, first, I know this question has been asked before several times.  None of the solutions seem to have helped (I think a lot of them are outdated).

I'm using Cocoa Pods to include third party frameworks.  For a few weeks, the integration was working fine.  Then suddenly the Pods_[nameofproject].framework Pods_[nameofproject]Tests.framework and Pods_[nameofproject]UITests.framework all gradually started turning red.  Now the frameworks I imported through CocoaPods aren't being found by Xcode.  I also have a few other Frameworks that I imported before I started using CocoaPods, and some of those (but not all of them) are red as well.

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESlz6.png)

Here is the list of things I've tried:
1) Delete derived date 
2) pod deintegrate/pod install 
3) include $(inherited) in Framework Search Paths
4) follow the troubleshooting on the cocoapods site 
5) restart Xcode
6) clean and build
7) clean and build on generic iOS device

Anything I'm missing here?  I must have done something to cause this - I doubt it would just stop on its own - but I'm completely at a loss what it could be.

Edit: Forgot to add that that Pods_[nameofproject].framework [appears to be grayed out in my linked binaries menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jCNa.png)

Comment: Are you opening the nameOfProject.xcworkspace file in xcode?? Or .xcproject

Comment: I’m using the .xcworkspace

Comment: Any insight on this?

Comment: Can you also post your podfile? And cocoapods version

Comment: Version is cocoapods-1.4.0.beta.1  [here's the podfile](https://imgur.com/sFKtSMv)

Comment: Just an update on this.  The pods.framework file will come back from time to time, but then it will inevitably go back to being red and  Xcode can't find it.  This issue is driving me crazy!!

Comment: So I guess NO ONE has this problem?  It's so fickle.  In an out almost at will.  I never know from one clean to the next whether I can actually code or not...

Comment: I appreciate the simple list of troubleshooting steps, even if this did not solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I never got an answer on this, but the answer is effectively that you don’t need to worry about it.  The app can still be tested/run with the pods in red.

Comment: Hi @Trent, did you manage to solve this issue? I'm having a similar issue. All my pods_[target].framework files are grayed. My app runs just fine on a real device and simulator but my OCD is not letting me sleep at night.